# Does d3js uses any technique to prevent excessive reflow?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, reflow

I was just reading an article on [writing fast memory efficient javascript](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/05/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/) and on the section "Minimizing Reflows" it alerts about doing individual DOM appending operations like:

```
function addDivs(element) {
  var div;
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i ++) {
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = 'Heya!';
    element.appendChild(div);
  }
}
```

After this function the author writes:

*"Simply appending each new div directly to the element **could** trigger 20 reflows."*

So the author doesn't say that it does. Since I heavily use [d3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3), I went to look at the source code on [github](https://github.com/mbostock/d3) to check if they had any comments on `reflow` or any usage of `DocumentFragment` (although this could be achieved with other techniques).

**My question is:** does anyone know if d3.js employs any technique to reduce reflows, or does it leave that optimization to the browser?

Thanks.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, D3 doesn't use any such techniques. I'm not sure how it would anyway, as things that would trigger reflows are results of user code.

Comment: D3 manipulates the DOM directly when you do .append()? if it takes 1000 div appends it could batch them in a frame using the mentioned DocumentFragment (or other technique) to prevent 1000 DOM changes? Does it make sense to you @LarsKotthoff?

Comment: Yes it manipulates the DOM directly and I'm not aware of any batching taking place.

Comment: it might have been a design decision, trading off a bit of speed here or there by having clear process and reducing risk by a very high margin that something could go wrong. Thanks @LarsKotthoff for your comments.